# Az login error: "The ID token is not yet valid. Make sure your computer's time and time zone are both correct."

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, azure-cli

When trying to use `az login` from WSL2 I got the following error:

The ID token is not yet valid. Make sure your computer's time and time zone are both correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered my WSL did not have the same system time as Windows, not sure why, but running `sudo hwclock -s` fixed this.

Comment: This shall be marked as "Answered" Thanks !